# Remotely running SSIS packages using create_execution ends up as Anonymous

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run an SSIS Package in the following environment (all database servers are SQL 2012)

server01 - Client machine

server02 - SSIS Server

server03 - Database

On the client I run a PowerShell script to choose one of the SSIS packages installed on the SSIS server, this is to allow variation on what is run without having to resort to writing multiple Jobs.  With a configuration file I can run any variation of tasks on the SSIS Server.  I can connect and start the SSIS packages that run on the SSIS server (server02), but whenever I run a job that connects to the Database (server03) the execution fails as an anonymous user.

I can see the caller is correct in the SSIS log, and I have set up permissions to allow for [remote access to the catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2012/03/20/ssis-catalog-access-control-tips.aspx).  I wasn't sure if the issue I  see where remote access is failing due to:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

is caused by the double hop problem where the SQL permissions cannot delegate from server02 to server03.

Can you do this with SQL 2012 or am I out of luck?

Comment: [Check here](http://serverfault.com/questions/273989/double-hop-problem-with-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Smells like an issue with the account that runs Server02 may not be properly set up for delegation. `setspn` will likely be your, or your domain admin's, friend. But, let's walk through some stuff. When you run the stored procedure on 02, are you connecting as a domain user or a SQL Server login? What account runs the SQL Server service on 02?

Comment: I wasn't aware of setspn, will check into that.  When connecting to server02 it is done as a domain User that has SQL access on server02 and server03.  SQL Server is running as Local System, the agent is running as a domain User but not one I am using in this scenario

Comment: @billinkc I think this may be delegation, does the account that runs SQL Server need to be set for this?  Or just the account I want to use to run remotely on server03?